# Specify working directory with MSVC compiler

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

So I have a project structure like this:

```
/
    build/
    data/
    include/
    src/
    build.bat
```

My build.bat looks like this:

```
@echo off
pushd build
cl -Zi /EHsc ../src/*.cpp /I.. /Fepea1
```

It produces the executable, great. Now I have some data I have to read from `data/` directory. Now the executable is in `build/` directory, so I would have to copy it to the root directory or I would have to use relative path (like `../data`). But I don't want to do that, cuz I don't know how will I be releasing this project (so I just want `path =  "data/`). In Visual Studio there was a way to specify projects working directory. Can I do this with `cl.exe`? Or do I need to use relative paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run the executable from the data folder.
..\build\out.exe and it will run from the data context.

You can do this using cmd.exe

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I would like to specify this in code, possibly without relative paths

Comment: If you want to put it inside your code then **SetCurrentDirectory** should be what you are looking for.